# Merging data and filling in missing data

Tags: r, merging-data

I have two sets of data:

| Unique ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

| Date |
| --- |
| 2020 |
| 2021 |
| 2022 |

Is there a way to merge this so the data looks like below?

| Unique ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 1 | 2021 |
| 1 | 2022 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2021 |
| 2 | 2022 |
| 3 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2021 |
| 3 | 2022 |

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this work for you

```
> df1 <- data.frame(UniqueID = 1:3)

> df2 <- data.frame(Date = 2020:2022)

> expand.grid(c(df1, df2))
  UniqueID Date
1        1 2020
2        2 2020
3        3 2020
4        1 2021
5        2 2021
6        3 2021
7        1 2022
8        2 2022
9        3 2022
```

Comment: Or with `crossing(df1, df2)`

Comment: @akrun Great, my bro! Is it from `tidyr`?

Comment: yes it is from tidyr